# How to archive files with 7zip directly for a .7z without extracting it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, archive, 7zip

I know how to archive files or to extract with 7zip (in Windows).
I know that WinRAR tools can archive files from another archives. Something like

```
    winrar -a dest_archive.rar origin_archive.zip/toto.txt
```

This seems not possible with 7z. Currently here is what i'm trying

```
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a "toto.zip" tata.7z\tata.txt
```

I know i could extract the whole archive (with 'e' option) then archive the file i want but this extract operation is one too many.

Comment: I am sorry but you are not very clear, `a` Adds files to a 7z file, so it should work. If it doesn't give more details what doesn't work

Comment: It sounds like you want to move a file from one archive (.7z) to another (.7z). Is that correct? If so, I don't think 7-Zip performs that action natively. It seems that 7-Zip only works on one archive at a time. I suspect that WinRAR only appears to do it by hiding the fact that it's extracting the file to a temporary location, then adding it to another archive, then deleting it. This shouldn't be too hard to automate, though.

Comment: Yes, it's what i want to do: move a file from one archive to another (at least in memory without temporary extract). But as said below, it's not natively possible with 7zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7-zip doesn't provide this functionality. You'd have to do it yourself.
Here's a quick demo. The relative file path (in the source .7z) is the first argument. The other args are the 7-Zip archives (source, then dest).

```
SETLOCAL 

SET "FILE_TO_MOVE=%~1"
SET "SOURCE_ARCHIVE=%~2"
SET "TARGET_ARCHIVE=%~3"

ECHO File: %FILE_TO_MOVE%
ECHO Source: %SOURCE_ARCHIVE%
ECHO Target: %TARGET_ARCHIVE%

SET "TEMP_DIR=%TEMP%\7z_temp_%RANDOM%"
IF EXIST "%TEMP_DIR%" RMDIR /S /Q "%TEMP_DIR%"
MKDIR "%TEMP_DIR%"

@ECHO Before copy...
7z.exe l "%TARGET_ARCHIVE%

7z.exe x -o"%TEMP_DIR%" "%SOURCE_ARCHIVE%" "%FILE_TO_MOVE%"
pushd "%TEMP_DIR%"
7z.exe a "%TARGET_ARCHIVE%" "%FILE_TO_MOVE%"
popd
RMDIR /S /Q "%TEMP_DIR%"

@ECHO After copy...
7z.exe l "%TARGET_ARCHIVE%
```

One quirk about this solution is that the target will probably need to be a fully qualified path (because you're changing to a different directory before referring to it). Since I don't know precisely how you intend to perform this operation, I can't propose a better solution that specifying an absolute path.

Comment: The question asks for "without extracting it" -- this example extracts.

Comment: "without extracting it" is _practically_ nonsense. It's almost certainly getting extracted behind the scenes, even if the program does it for you and doesn't say so. I proposed this as a workable solution to an impossible problem (see my comment on the question).

Comment: Jubjub: Then the right answer is "you can't do that", not "here's an answer which does something you explicitly asked not to do". Even if the bits are getting extracted by the Winrar example underneath, they're likely not taking space proportional to the size of data stored in the archive, nor do the extracted bits need to be written out to disk (can all happen in memory).

Comment: The question wasn't very clear IMO but it does explicitly say that the OP doesn't want to extract the whole archive.  Jubjub's solution does extract the single file and add it to the archive - which is the desired operation as I read the question.  I don't know of any archiver that does this in memory, they all use a temporary file.

Comment: Ok it's what i thought: archive without extracting is nonsense. What a pity! (At least with 7zip).
So the solution here above to do a temporary extract of the file is the best solution for my problem. 

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get into the concept exposed is

```
7z e -so tata.7z tata.txt | 7z a -sitata.txt toto.7z
```

This will extract `tata.txt` from source file, send output to stdout, and recompress into target file reading from stdin.

BUT file needs to be decompressed/recompressed.

AND it seems that .zip interface is not compatible with this kind of operation. 7z, bzip2, gzip work without problems.